# DNN NavigateURL causes Warning in 9.5.1 solution in basic?

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke

I got this warning in some very old Basic code I am managing. Web solutions are generally in C#.

Can anyone point me at an example solution in Basic please?

NavigateURL deprecated in 9.4.0 scheduled for removal in 11.0.0

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace Globals.NavigateUrl with the new INavigationManager interface as it will be removed in version 11. See [here](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/issues/3153).

Here are some threads in the DNN Community forum that might help:

[NavigationManager](https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/794)

[Upgrading from 9.1.1 to 9.4.4 and Globals.NavigateURL](https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/890)

The examples mentioned are all in C#, but it is not a question of the language but of the method/interface used. So it should be easy to translate it to VB.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same problem.
Maybe you could try with:

- Response.Redirect(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Url) to replace NavigateURL()
- Response.Redirect(EditURL()) to replace NavigateURL() with parameters

Comment: While this didn't tell me precisely what I required, it gave me enough info to get me there!  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to look at Michael Tobisch post. At this time, I had not understood this new concept. You also could read this interesting post: https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/2002